# Livewire Chart Components Show Only Latest Year

Tags: laravel, charts, laravel-livewire, apexcharts

I've Tried to Convert My Laravel Application To Livewire for, but i have some issues

This Is My Chart Class

```
class Chart extends Component
{
    public $paketTender;
    public $paketNonTender;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->loadChart();
        // dd($this->paketTender);
    }

    private function loadChart()
    {

        $this->paketTender      = DB::table('siapel_dokumen')
                                    ->select(
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_hps)) as total_hps"),
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_pagu)) as total_pagu"),
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_kontrak)) as total_kontrak"),
                                    DB::raw("tahun as tahun")
                                    )
                                        ->where([['id_jenis_dokumen', '=','1'],['progres','=','100']])
                                        ->orderBy('created_at','ASC')
                                        ->groupBy('tahun')
                                        ->get();

        $this->paketNonTender   = DB::table('siapel_dokumen')
                                    ->select(
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_hps)) as total_hps"),
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_pagu)) as total_pagu"),
                                    DB::raw("(sum(nilai_kontrak)) as total_kontrak"),
                                    DB::raw("tahun as tahun")
                                    )
                                        ->where([['id_jenis_dokumen', '=','2'],['progres','=','100']])
                                        ->orderBy('created_at','ASC')
                                        ->groupBy('tahun')
                                        ->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $data = [
            'paketTender' => $this->paketTender,
            'paketNonTender' => $this->paketNonTender,
        ];

        return view('livewire.landing.chart',$data);
    }
}
```

And This Is The Result from DataDump

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1780 ▼ // app/Livewire/Landing/Chart.php:16
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1777 ▼
      +"total_hps": 49211444352.0
      +"total_pagu": 49864777856.0
      +"total_kontrak": 47957017472.0
      +"tahun": 2022
    }
    1 => {#1776 ▼
      +"total_hps": 242326738080.0
      +"total_pagu": 52489993216.0
      +"total_kontrak": 1558087082816.0
      +"tahun": 2023
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

And This Is The View of 'Chart'

```
@push('scripts')
<script>

    function pecahan(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    }
    // =========== 1. Perbandingan Nilai Kontrak Pagu dan HPS Tender ===========
    var options = {
        series: [{
        name: 'Total Pagu',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_pagu }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Total HPS',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_hps }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Total Kontrak',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_kontrak }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }],
        chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 250
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: '55%',
        borderRadius: 6,
        },
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: 2,
        colors: ['transparent']
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: [
        @foreach ($paketTender as $data)
            '{{ $data->tahun }}',
        @endforeach
        ],
    },
    yaxis: {
    labels:{
        formatter: (value) => {
            return `Rp. ${pecahan(value)}`;
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: "Rupiah (Rp)",
    },
    },
    fill: {
        opacity: 1
    },
    tooltip: {
        y: {
        formatter: (value) => {
            return `Rp. ${pecahan(value)}`;
        },
        }
    },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#tender"), options);
    chart.render();

    // =========== 2. Perbandingan Nilai Kontrak Pagu dan HPS Tender ===========
    var options = {
        series: [{
        name: 'Total Pagu',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketNonTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_pagu }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Total HPS',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketNonTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_hps }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Total Kontrak',
        data: [
            @foreach ($paketNonTender as $data)
                {{ $data->total_kontrak }},
            @endforeach
        ]
    }],
        chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 250
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: '55%',
        borderRadius: 6,
        },
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    stroke: {
        show: true,
        width: 2,
        colors: ['transparent']
    },
    xaxis: {
        categories: [
            @foreach ($paketNonTender as $data)
                '{{ $data->tahun }}',
            @endforeach
        ],
    },
    yaxis: {
    labels:{
        formatter: (value) => {
            return `Rp. ${pecahan(value)}`;
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: "Rupiah (Rp)",
    },
    },
    fill: {
        opacity: 1
    },
    tooltip: {
        y: {
        formatter: (value) => {
            return `Rp. ${pecahan(value)}`;
        },
        }
    },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#nontender"), options);
    chart.render();

</script>

@endpush
```

But the result is not what i am expected, it supposed to be show all year, but ony show the latest years when i am using livewire.
[image: Onlu Show Latest year with livewire]

and this is the result without livewire using the same query

[image]

i really appreciate for every answer
thank you

ps : sorry for my broken english